# Fourier component of electric field

Tags: optics, electric-fields, fourier-transform

The [paper](https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-13-14-5353&id=84900) deals with Terahertz beam production from ZnTe emitters.

We've eqn. for generated THz beam from an area element of emitter crystal giveb by:-

$E_{THz}(t)=K_{eff}W_{opt}T(t)$ - eqn(1)

where,
$K_{eff}$ = factor describing efficiency of THz production, independent of $W_{opt}$.
$W_{opt}$ = optical fluence of the incident pulse
T(t) describes temporal form of the pulse, with $\int T^2(t)dt=1$

Further,
$W_{opt}(r)=\frac{2J_{opt}}{A_{opt}}exp\left (- \frac{2r^2}{r^2_{opt}} \right )$ - Guassian profile of incident beam.

where, $J_{opt}$=Pulse energy, $A_{opt}$=$\pi r^2_{opt}$=$1/e^2$ area of the incident beam.

After some calculations, we get: -

$J_{THz}=c\epsilon_0 K^2_{eff} \frac{J^2_{opt}}{A_{opt}}$ - Total energy of generated THz pulse

### These are all given to us

Then, it's written "Applying the Gaussian beam theory to each Fourier component of $E_{THz}$ in eqn. (1), one can derive an expressoin for the on-axis THz field at the detector as:"

$E_{det}(r=0,t)=E^0_{det}\frac{d}{dt}T(t)$
where, $E^0_{det}=K_{eff}\frac{J_{opt}}{2\pi c f_{det}}$ - where $f_{det}$ is the effective focusing length of the focusing element.

### Question

What exactly is applying Gaussian beam theory to each Fourier component in eqn.(1)? From what I understand, we just need to integrate eqn.(1) over the emitting surface and put r=0 to get the on-axis electric field. What's the purpose of carrying out Fourier transform?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Title - Large-area electro-optic ZnTe terahertz emitters. Authors - T. Löffler, T. Hahn, M. Thomson, F. Jacob, and H. G. Roskos